# Bulk collecting with LIMIT clause into nested table in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

As the title says, how to bulk collect into a nested table with LIMIT clause?
In the following examples, cur_data is a nested table which gets overwritten on the subsequent BULK COLLECT. I have seen EXTEND used for adding data to a nested table. Is there any way to do something similar with BULIK COLLECT?

```
  OPEN cur;
  LOOP
      FETCH cur bulk collect INTO cur_data LIMIT 500;
      EXIT WHEN cur_data%COUNT=0;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE cur;
  /*Data gets overwritten with empty cursor--> No data in cur_data here*/


  OPEN cur;
  FETCH cur bulk collect INTO cur_data;
  CLOSE cur;
  /*No Problems--> All data fetched into cur_data */
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: LIMIT is supported with BULK COLLECT in oracle. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems020.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand the problem you are trying to solve.

If you want to load every row the is fetched from the cursor into your collection, there is no point to using the LIMIT clause.  Simply

```
OPEN cur;
FETCH cur
 BULK COLLECT INTO cur_data;
<<do something with the data>>
CLOSE cur;
```

If you want to use the LIMIT clause, that implies that you want to process a subset of the data returned from the cursor at a time in order to limit the amount of the server's PGA that is allocated to your collection.  Assuming you are doing that

```
OPEN cur;
LOOP
  FETCH cur
   BULK COLLECT INTO cur_data LIMIT 500;
  EXIT WHEN cur_data%count = 0;
  <<do something with the 500 elements in cur_data>>
END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
```

It doesn't make any sense to fetch the data 500 rows at a time inside your loop and then do something with the collection outside of the loop.

Comment: I remember reading BULK COLLECTING everything at once, would consume more memory than limiting the number of records with LIMIT clause, especially if there are several millions of records. This is why I would like to use the LIMIT clause. Sorry I didn't mention this in the question.

Comment: @digdug - The Yes, since the data in the collection is stored in the server's PGA memory, it is relatively expensive and a good idea to process data in chunks.  If you're going to process the data in chunks, though, you'd process it inside the loop as I show in my second example.  The consumption of memory is related to the number of elements in the collection so if you want to save memory, you won't have all the data in the collection at once.